# Ignore patern for long js test description

Tags: javascript, regex, eslint, tslint

I have `tslint` rule like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "max-line-length": [true, {"limit": 120, "ignore-pattern": "^import [^,]+ from"}],
  } 
}
```

which works well for imports.

Now I want to ignore pattern for long test descriptions:

```
  description('My awesome very long desc...',() => {
    it('My other very long desc...', () => {

    })
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Alas, there is no way to do this in TSLint. There is an [open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/3905) accepting pull requests now.

That being said, TSLint's maintainers recommend using [Prettier](https://prettier.io) instead of TSLint for formatting concerns such as this one.